# The best way to distribute this framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, distribution, software-distribution, hibernate-validator

I just created a framework (it would be more accurate to describe it as an integration), and I'm wondering what would be the best way to distribute it. The project is mavenized and uses Spring 3, but I am a novice in both areas and I am not sure what would be the best way to distribute this.

The framework involves an integration between a Javascript library that I created, Spring 3 (the web MVC part), and Hibernate Validator.

- I have a `pom.xml` for the whole project.
- I have a `src/main/java` (properly namespaced) with the classes relevant to the integration.
- I have a `webapp` directory with a `js` folder that contains the Javascript files necessary for this integration.
- I have a `WEB-INF/tlds` directory with a tld for a custom tag implemented in Java.
- I have a `WEBINF/tags` directory for a custom tag.
- I have an `applicationContext.xml` in `src/main/resources`.
- I have a `springmvc-servlet.xml` in `WEB-INF`.
- I have a `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` (looks to be standard and out of the box; I don't recall making any changes).
- I have a `src/test/java/` that includes tests for the integration framework

What files/directories should I include/exclude, and what would be a good way to distribute this integration (for Spring 3 that is)? Is there a standard?

**UPDATE**

Sorry I wasn't cleared about what I meant by "distribute" :) I meant in the sense that other developers can include this framework as an artifact in their project (perhaps as a jar), similar to how libraries are distributed. I'm just confused by the fact that there is webapp-specific stuff in there.

Comment: Are you able to deploy and run your web application? I don't see anything wrong with your current integration. Only minor thing is to group all the spring configuration files inside a subfolder in WEB-INF but this requires you to properly configure the DispatcherServlet in web.xml. I normally have applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF\config folder. But, of course, you can have it anywhere since Spring support classpath lookup.

Comment: sounds like a good use of Maven archetypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a maven webapp project into a framework will be a bit of hassle for other people to use. The problem isn't about what you should include/exclude but what the downstream webapp project should include/exclude. The downstream project will need to exclude the `web.xml` from its war dependency and need to make sure that it doesn't contain file/folder names which collide with its depending war files.

Normally, `web.xml` is exculded by `maven-war-plugin` but configurations files like logger configurations will not be exculded by default and it will be crash with the downstream project's. Since the `web.xml` is exculded, the downstream project will not be able to know what are the servlet definitions in its war dependencies. You will need to copy or define them accordingly yourself.

Since you do not have any changes to your `web.xml`, I think you are not going to run it as webapp. You should make it into jar package, instead of war package, and convert it to normal maven jar project, i.e. remove `src/main/webapp` folder

Although it is possible to have a war dependency, I highly recommend not to.

**Update**

From your comment, that's what I am worried about too. It is probably the only reason you have to use war package. So you will need to keep in mind that:

1. If you have the spring dispatcher configuration xml and bean definition under `src/main/webapp`, make sure to include/exculde them in your downstream project correctly using configuration setting for `maven-war-plugin`. Make sure the filename won't crash with the downstream project. You will need to becareful when you want to reuse beans definition since it may not be configured to suit the need of the downstream project. In many case, you will end up writing a new definition. **Tip:** putting them as resources under unique package name in the classpath is the safest and easiest way.
2. The `web.xml` have to be there in order to make a war package, but it will be exculded from downstream war project by  `maven-war-plugin`. You need to inculde this plugin in your  downstream project. If you have any servlet definition in `web.xml`, it will have be redefined in downstream project `web.xml`.
3. Becareful with folder/file collision in under `src/main/webapp` folder.

In summary, the main concern is the place where you put xml configuration nd how you want to include/exclude it in the downstream project (not in your integration).

Comment: Unfortunately, the src/main/webapp contains the tld's and tag files that are necessary to the project. How would I distribute these?

Comment: @Vivin Paliath I have updated the answer, I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "distribute" here. :)

If you are merely distributing to fellow developers so that they can work on the same project, perhaps you want to invoke `mvn clean` to remove target folder, compiled classes, etc. This command will take care of the inclusion and exclusion of files/directories. All you need to do is to zip the entire project up and "distribute" it. When the developer imports this project into workspace, they are obtain all the jars through your pom.xml. Pom.xml, in my opinion, is the most important piece of any Maven project.

If you want end user to be able to run your project rather than making changes to your code, you may want to invoke `mvn package` to create the war file. This way, your user can drop this war file into the application server and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Maven WAR overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) also described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776874/maven-jsp-files-in-dependency).

Also create an example - probably from the webapp you already have - of all these and generate a [Maven archetype](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/) from it.

Comment: So when you said tld's this would include the tag files as well, as well as the javascript files?

Comment: Tag files yes, JavaScripts no. Your project structure should change so that all the non-java-source files would be at `src/main/resources` in appropriate subdirectories. For instance [spring-webmvc](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc) distributes TLDs as part of the JAR, [check out their project structure](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web.servlet/). The JavaScripts should be distributed separately since there's no good way (that I know of) to include them properly to the project from a JAR.

Comment: I upgraded my answer as I found out about the WAR overlays. Those could work for distributing this kind of framework.